# How to call an index value from an itertools permutation without converting it to a list?

Tags: python, indexing, permutation, python-itertools

I need to create all combinations of these characters:

```
'0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM. '
```

That are 100 letters long, such as:

```
'0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001'
```

I'm currently using this code:

```
import itertools
babel = itertools.product(k_c, repeat = 100)
```

This code works, but I need to be able to return the combination at a certain index, however `itertools.product` does not support indexing, turning the product into a list yields a MemoryError, and iterating through the product until I reaches a certain value takes too long for values over a billion.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Iterate on th result of product and counting the posittion ?

Comment: @azro I don't get what you mean? Sorry

Comment: `for idx, item in enumerate(babel): if idx==123456:print(item`

Comment: I think this is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Tried this, but same problem of it taking too long occurs. Is there no way to do this quickly, like calling a list index?

Comment: No there is no way of doing that itertools generate the permutations on the *fly*

Comment: @DaniMesejo Rephrased the question

Comment: But why do you need them at a specific index? Why are you going to do with that? Are you planning on doing this repeatedly? What problem do you have that you need to fetch a permutation at a particular *index* ?

Comment: The *output* will have [lexicographic ordering](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) so specific indices will differ based on the input. Have you considered that?

Comment: Did you consider any of the Q&A's returned with a search of `python get the ith permutation site:stackoverflow.com`?

Comment: This is very much still an XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

With 64 characters and 100 letters there will be 64^100 combinations.  For each value of the first letter, there will be 64^99 combinations of the remaining letters, then 64^98, 64^97, and so on.

This means that your Nth combination can be expressed as N in base 64 where each "digit" represents the index of the letter in the string.

An easy solution would be to build the string recursively by progressively determining the index of each position and getting the rest of the string with the remainder of N:

```
chars = '0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM. '

def comboNumber(n,size=100):
    if size == 1: return chars[n]
    return comboNumber(n//len(chars),size-1)+chars[n%len(chars)]
```

output:

```
c = comboNumber(123456789000000000000000000000000000000000000123456789)
print(c)
# 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000059.90jDxZuy6drpQdWATyZ8007dNJs


c = comboNumber(1083232247617211325080159061900470944719547986644358934)
print(c)
# 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000Python.Person says Hello World
```

Conversely, if you want to know at which combination index a particular string is located, you can compute the base64 value by combining the character index (digit) at each position:

```
s = "Python.Person says Hello World" # leading zeroes are implied
i = 0
for c in s:
    i = i*len(chars)+chars.index(c)
print(i) # 1083232247617211325080159061900470944719547986644358934
```

*You are now this much closer to understanding base64 encoding which is the same thing applied to 24bit numbers coded over 4 characters (i.e 3 binary bytes --> 4 alphanumeric characters) or any variant thereof*